# How to ensure user selects the top card in a deck of cards in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I've got a deck of cards which I've placed as sprites in my Unity game (each card as an individual sprite). They're positioned as a messy pile.... how can I ensure that the top card in the deck is picked up first? i.e. I don't want the user to select the 5th card down even though it would be partially visible...

Comment: Do the top most cards have a higher z index?

Comment: have a field in your game controller (or somewhere else that makes more sense in your architecture) that keeps track of what card is on top. then when you detect a click on any card, refer to that field.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. @RyanWilson Unfortunately it wouldn't matter if I changed the z index as they're not placed exactly over each other. I've made it so that you can see the other cards protruding from the deck underneath. As it is at the moment the user can select the edges of the cards underneath.

Comment: @Ruzihm do you have a code sample of how I could achieve that? Even though I'm familiar with C#, I've only just started using Unity and therefore not sure how everything ties together! :/

Comment: Create a script, call it "GameManager". Give it a `public GameObject topCard` field. Put it on an empty GameObject named "Game Manager".  Drag the top card gameobject in your scene into the Game Manager's "Top Card" field visible in the inspector.  In the method you call when a click happens, get a reference to the game manager component (cache the result of `GameObject.Find("Game Manager").GetComponent<GameManager>()` or make `GameManager` a [singleton](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton) ) then you can get the top card gameobject with `gameMan.topCard`.

Comment: If there are not very many of these card instances you could just search all of the cards for the topmost Z value when *any* card in the pile is clicked. Assigning the variable for the top-most card would probably require this type of search anyways. You could also use a data-first approach: use a list to store the order of your cards and set the sprite positions based on that data structure...

Comment: If you want the player to be able to keep drawing the top card among the cards that are left, the most scalable way to do this is to have some kind of means of determining which card is at the top at runtime. Exactly how to do that depends on how you're arranging the cards-- if they're being placed at different z positions or if you're assigning different sorting orders to them. We need to know more information in that case.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. You're right @Ruzihm I do need to ensure that the player always takes the top card in the pile. I'm sorry for sounding quite simple but would you happen to have a code example of how I could achieve this check during runtime? I don't have much of an idea of how to implement it :/ There will only ever be roughly 6 cards in the deck. That's all I've done at the moment is place the cards on the canvas in a messy pile look... but yes I'd always want to ensure that only the top-most card is selectable no matter how many cards are taken from the deck.

Comment: in the inspector, set their z values to be different(this will cause them to be ordered by z), tag them all with "card". Then in code, you can use `GameObject[] cards = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("card");`  Then compare their `cards[i].transform.position.z` to find the one that has the smallest `z` and that's the one on top.  You could do the `FindXYZ` call & find the top every time a user clicks. Or, you could put it in the `Start()` of  a singleton, then sort into a list by `z`, and save that sorted list to a field there.

Comment: Select the card how? Maybe disable all their `RayCast Target` properties except the most top one?

Comment: @Ruzihm thank you so much for your help.I'm a bit confused with what you said "tag them all with 'card' "...? Do you think there would be a simpler way of doing it if I only have 5 cards?

Comment: @Lloyd [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) is what I mean by tag. Add "card" as a new tag, then select each card in the hierarchy (if you're using Windows, you can hold the **ctrl** key to select multiple things at a time), and change their tag to "card"

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would use to solve this issue, is to parent all your deck cards to one parent gameobject which catches the click-events (the unity event system raycasts the leaves first and if it finds no handler on the leaf, it will look for a handler in the parent and then the parent's parent... you get the idea).

If the monobehaviour catching click-events on the parent knows which of those cards is on the top, it can then trigger what ever functionality you want on that card.

EDIT:

```
//something along these lines:
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class CardDeckManager : Monobehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    [serializeField]
    private List<GameObject> _cards; // If I were you I'd have a Monobehaviour class "Card" or so, which each card has, then you can replace BoxCollider2D with that and access functionality for cards in the deck from here

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerClickEventData data)
    {
        var topmostCard = _cards[0];
        _cards.RemoveAt(0); // remove the topmost card from the deck
        DoSomethingWith(topmostCard); // and have it played
        // For example move it to the center of the table... and have it affect the game logic
    }

    // assign _cards these in editor, or generate them programmatically
}
```

Important: make sure you have an EventSystem, and a raycaster on the camera

Comment: Thank you @Daveloper for your help. That sounds like a good idea what you said...would you have a code example of how I could achieve it? I'm new to Unity so not entirely sure yet how the code and interface objects interact :/

Answer (score 0):

Since it's game, I am going to assume that there is something like a Game Manager or Deck Manager class which keeps track of the cards on the table in an Array(or List). The order of the cards should match the order of the card references in the array, as long as all the card operations(shuffling etc.) are done on the array.

Once that is in place, you can simply add an event listener function in that class which is called any time the user tries to pick up any card. If that card is the last card in the array then let it be picked, otherwise not.